# Transmitter design methods using 0201 SMD

Tags: surface-mount, transmitter

I have some experience designing an IOT transmitter (315MHz/345MHz/433MHz) using 0603 SMD parts, but am considering building a transmitter for production using 0201 parts. My question is, what is a good work flow using 0201 parts, especially for the antenna matching/filter network? I am used to swapping out dozens of parts in the matching network while tuning and getting spurious emissions below the minimums. But I'm guessing 0201 parts take the process to a new level.

Thoughts?

Comment: Not all values are available in 0201, especially inductors.

Comment: The process isn't going to change much, you're just going to need good tweezers, a steady hand, and a microscope if you didn't use one before.

Comment: Could you explain your last line? "..a new level." What do you mean by that? They're smaller, yes, but that just means lower parasitics.

Comment: @uint128_t By "new level" I was referring to the work flow and handling. I wouldn't expect the circuit theory to change.